# capture router packets using wireshark

Tags: wireshark

i have two devices connected wireless on the same router. the one is my pc and the other is the smartphone. is it possible that, if i have instal the wireshark on the pc to capture the data/packets that the smartphone is sending and receiveing to a certain server which i know its ip? my pc has windows 2007 and the smartphone is an android device if its makes any difference
i try to install the shart for root on the android device but it is not working due to that my android is not rooted, and i don't wont to lose everything from my phone in order to root it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using Cain & Abel. It will capture packets from your smartphone to router. To explain a bit, C&A will do ARP poisoning-  meaning all the devices on your wireless network will assume that your desktop is the new router and all the incoming/outgoing traffic will go through your desktop. In this way you can capture the traffic on your phone without rooting it.
I hope this helps.

Comment: ok i have donwload it but i can't find how to capture the smartphone ip to check the data that are send and receive

Comment: You should read the help section of this tool. It's very well documented.